# Android app that remotely takes photos

Tags: android, photography, remote-access, webcam

I am looking to send a request to my phone's IP over the LAN using `curl` and get back an image from the camera.

At the moment, I am doing this with [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam), but I don't need the video stream – just still photos. Because it's streaming video, the app absolutely kills my phone battery, and is useless after running for an hour.

All of the other apps that I can find with remote photo functionality are either webcam apps with no ability to disable video streaming, or sketchy "spy" apps that require far too many permissions and provide features I don't want (like remotely reading SMS messages).

Features I want:

- Remotely trigger taking photos when a request is made
- Use flash when taking a remotely-triggered photo
- Web server that serves images so I can request with `curl`
- Only takes photos, no video
- Photos are taken and transferred in full resolution
- Only works over LAN, no cloud
- **Strong** preference for FOSS applications
- Bonus points if battery metadata is also made accessible to `curl` via the same app/server

Note: I am open to video-streaming apps that have an option to fully disable video and only provide still images.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google lead to this https: //ikeymonitor.com/remotely-take-photos-with-the-spy-camera-app.html. From what I understand it has most of what you require but I've never used it.

Comment: While I appreciate you taking a look, this has some things I very specifically *don't* want: I don't want a "spy" app that requires too many permissions and has too much unnecessary functionality that puts my phone and data at risk. I also don't want an app that syncs data to a cloud server, and would prefer for the app to be FOSS. I very specifically listed these requirements in my post, and do not intend to award the bounty to this answer.

Comment: Understandable and sorry for such bad answer. Hopefully this list will serve you better. https://cancioneira.com/7-best-free-spy-camera-apps-android/